# Fastest way to programmatically replace text in a Word document

Tags: .net, replace, ms-word, ms-office

The task is to replace specific keywords in a Word document using .NET. What would be the fastest and most reliable way to make it retaining original formatting and document structure?

Comment: Does it have to be .NET? Word's got a full-featured macro language (Visual Basic for Applications) that'll do this. You can even get it to record a macro for you in VBA. Combine this with the mailmerge functionality, and job done. If you *really* need to use .NET, you can fairly easily hand-convert the VBA to .NET and OLE Automation. Or do you need to do this without actually having Word installed? Oh. and what's "fastest"? Quickest to implement? Fastest performance on a single document? Fastest performance on multiple documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have word installed then it's pretty trivial.

Referencing the Word doc assembly from the GAC. You can load up a word document and replace data in it.

This is from an app I have here to print word documents by putting in client names and such. (cut and pasted sections)

```
    public void ReplaceWordDoc(ref Document doc, object data)
    {
        object missing = Missing.Value;

        List<ReplacerSearch> search = GetSearchList(data);

        foreach (var searchItem in search)
        {
            foreach (Range tmpRange in ((Document)doc).StoryRanges)
            {
                // Set the text to find and replace
                tmpRange.Find.Text = searchItem.Find;
                tmpRange.Find.Replacement.Text = searchItem.Replace;

                // Set the Find.Wrap property to continue (so it doesn't
                // prompt the user or stop when it hits the end of
                // the section)
                tmpRange.Find.Wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;

                // Declare an object to pass as a parameter that sets
                // the Replace parameter to the "wdReplaceAll" enum
                object replaceAll = WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;

                // Execute the Find and Replace -- notice that the
                // 11th parameter is the "replaceAll" enum object
                tmpRange.Find.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref replaceAll,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            }
        }
    }
```

^This part does the find/replace. The list of ReplacerSearch (wow bad name) is just two properties, Find, Replace. Find is the text to find, Replace is the text to replace with.

Then the code below, based on a given filename (path/name) it creates an instance of word (i think) and opens the document, does the replacement, and then you can save or print or what ever.

```
    object  fileName        = string.Empty,
            trueValue       = true,
            missing         = Missing.Value,
            falseValue      = false;
    var     app             = new ApplicationClass();
    var doc = new Document();

try
{
    doc = app.Documents.AddOld(ref fileName, ref missing);
    //doc = app.Documents.Add(ref fileName, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

    // Loops through the StoryRanges (sections of the Word doc)
    ReplaceWordDoc(ref doc, item);

    //Save or print...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Helpers.Logger.WriteToEventLog(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
}
finally
{
    if (doc != null)
    {
        doc.Close(ref falseValue, ref missing, ref missing);
    }
}

if (app != null)
{
    app.Application.Quit(ref falseValue, ref missing, ref missing);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The new Word files are essentially XML documents. You can open them as regular files in a language such as python, and then search for whatever terms you wan to replace. Once you find them, it's just a matter of changing it and saving the file.

This could probably be done with the strings library, though there may be a simpler way especially tailored to XML documents.

Edit: Same methodology should work for doing it in .NET, just noticed the tag now.

Comment: The OpenXML SDK is likely the way. it's .net, fairly easy to use, etc. Only issue is that if the "Words to find" are formatting inconsistently, say with the first word BOLD and the rest normal, the "word" won't appear as a single string in the xml, it'll be split into RUN objects, all you'll have to this parse the xml as applicable. this is no small task. Using .net to automate the find and replace is likely the quickest to implement and the should have reasonable performance as well. Word's FIND REPLACE, while not great, is certainly ok.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using MS Word's `Mail Merge` functionality, it was designed for this purpose.
Have a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301659

Answer (score 0):

You do not need word installed you can use python modules like python-docx to achieve this. Or if you do not want to write raw and complex code, you can try following REST API to achieve this.

https://rapidapi.com/more.sense.tech@gmail.com/api/document-filter1

It should be easy to call this from .NET